# Can Kafka API be used in a Spark RDD?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I want to write from spark to a kafka topic. I don't want to use its scala api because I don't want to have mixed code(java + scala). Is it ok to use kafka's own API to do this? Are there any drawbacks?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to check out [spark-kafka-writer](https://github.com/cloudera/spark-kafka-writer) which seems to solve what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about cloudera's spark-kafka-writer but I want to know what does it imply to use Kafka's own API and what are the drawbacks by doing this.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. There will be at least one producer per executor if that is to be considered a drawback..